# How many categories there are in a column for the same group in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, categories

I have a data frame (df) where I have the Directors (DirectorID) for two years (2006 and 2007) in 2 different companies (CompanyID) and their respective gender (M or F).

```
df <-
CompanyID   Name    Country ISIN     Director_2006  Gender_2006 Director_2007 Gender_2007   
25830      BANKxxx     Austria  AT000504  11734844255     M     11734844255      M       
25830      BANKxxx     Austria  AT000504  187836811559    F      5524344997      F        
25830      BANKxxx     Austria  AT000504    5524344997    F      5524354997      M        
25830      BANKxxx     Austria  AT000504    5524354997    M      5742347684      M        
25830      BANKxxx     Austria  AT000504    6613115791    M      40160443378     M          
12339      BANKyyy     Belgium  AT034003    5524344997    M      5524344997      M        
12339      BANKyyy     Belgium  AT034003    5524354997    M      5524354997      M
```

I would like to add more 5 columns after each gender columns, i.e. after "Gender_2006" and "Gender_2007", with the following information:

- Column 1: Numbers of female in that company in that year
- Column 2: Numbers of male in that company in that year
- Column 3: If there is at least one female in that company in that year I add the number 1, if there is not I add the number 0
- Column 4: Percentage of women (F) in that company in that year
- Column 5: Blau Index Calculation

The df_final is my expected final output.

```
df_final <-
CompanyID  Name  Country  ISIN   Director_2006 Gender_2006 F2006 M2006 Findex2006 Fperce2006  Blauindex2006  Director_2007  Gender_2007  F2007  M2007  Findex2007 Fperce2007  Blauindex2007     
25830    BANKxxx Austria AT000504 11734844255     M        2       3       1           0.4     0.25           11734844255        M         1     4       1         0.25           0.07      
25830    BANKxxx Austria AT000504 187836811559    F        NA      NA     NA            NA     NA              5524344997        F         NA    NA      NA        NA             NA           
25830    BANKxxx Austria AT000504 5524344997      F        NA      NA     NA            NA     NA              5524354997        M         NA    NA      NA        NA             NA
25830    BANKxxx Austria AT000504 5524354997      M        NA      NA     NA            NA     NA              5742347684      M           NA    NA      NA        NA             NA
25830    BANKxxx Austria AT000504 6613115791      M        NA      NA     NA            NA     NA              40160443378     M           NA    NA      NA        NA             NA
12339    BANKyyy Belgium AT034003 5524344997      M        0       2      0             0      0               5524344997      M           0     2       0         0              0
12339    BANKyyy Belgium AT034003 5524354997      M        NA      NA     NA            NA     NA              5524354997      M           NA    NA      NA        NA             NA
```

Please, can someone advise me? Thanks.

My data

```
df <- read.table(text = 
               "CompanyID   Name    Country ISIN     Director_2006  Gender_2006 Director_2007 Gender_2007  
                25830      BANKxxx     Austria  AT000504  11734844255     M     11734844255      M        
                25830      BANKxxx     Austria  AT000504  187836811559    F      5524344997      F       
                25830      BANKxxx     Austria  AT000504    5524344997    F      5524354997      M       
                25830      BANKxxx     Austria  AT000504    5524354997    M      5742347684      M       
                25830      BANKxxx     Austria  AT000504    6613115791    M      40160443378     M         
                12339      BANKyyy     Belgium  AT034003    5524344997    M      5524344997      M       
                12339      BANKyyy     Belgium  AT034003    5524354997    M      5524354997      M",
                header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: Do you think you can add the code to generate the first table. It will help people so they do not have to reproduce the first table, and you will get a faster response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following in `dplyr` the `group_by` clause indicates what you're grouping by, in this case companyID.  `mutate` will create the new rows based on the conditions you specified.  `select` just changes the ordering.

```
library(dplyr)
df  %>% group_by(CompanyID) %>%
    mutate(F2006 = sum(Gender_2006 == "F", na.rm = T),
            M2006 = sum(Gender_2006 == "M", na.rm = T),
            Findex2006 = as.integer(sum(Gender_2006 == "F", na.rm = T)>0),
            Fperce2006 = F2006/(F2006+M2006),
            F2007 = sum(Gender_2007 == "F", na.rm = T),
            M2007 = sum(Gender_2007 == "M", na.rm = T),
            Findex2007 = as.integer(sum(Gender_2007 == "F", na.rm = T)>0),
            Fperce2007 = F2007/(F2007+M2007)) %>% 
    select(-matches("2006|2007"),matches("2006"), matches("2007"))



# A tibble: 8 x 16
# Groups: CompanyID [2]
#   CompanyID Name    Country ISIN     Director_2006 Gender_2006 F2006 M2006 Findex2006 Fperce2006 Director_2007 Gender_2007
#       <int> <fct>   <fct>   <fct>            <dbl> <fct>       <int> <int>      <int>      <dbl>         <dbl> <fct>      
# 1     25830 BANKxxx Austria AT000504   11734844255 M               2     3          1      0.400   11734844255 M          
# 2     25830 BANKxxx Austria AT000504  187836811559 F               2     3          1      0.400    5524344997 F          
# 3     25830 BANKxxx Austria AT000504    5524344997 F               2     3          1      0.400    5524354997 M          
# 4     25830 BANKxxx Austria AT000504    5524354997 M               2     3          1      0.400    5742347684 M          
# 5     25830 BANKxxx Austria AT000504    6613115791 M               2     3          1      0.400   40160443378 M          
# 6     12339 BANKyyy Belgium AT034003    5524344997 M               0     2          0      0        5524344997 M          
# 7     12339 BANKyyy Belgium AT034003    5524354997 M               0     2          0      0        5524354997 M          
# 8     12339 BANKyyy Belgium AT034003            NA <NA>            0     2          0      0                NA <NA>
```

If you need all NA in the rows except the first one you can change the mutate to something like:

```
F2006 = ifelse(row_number()==1,sum(Gender_2006 == "F", na.rm = T),NA),
```